# Showing a portfolio is a self financing portfolio

Tags: stochastic-processes

I'm having some trouble understanding how you are able to use Ito's lemma to show in the example I've attached it's equal to $d\pi = 2BdB$ because I can't collapse the $dt$ term I've attached the Ito's lemma I'm using and I can't grasp what is the $a(X,t)$ term or $b(X,t)$ term, any help will be much appreciated[image][image]

Comment: Check your application of the Ito formula to compute $\mathrm{d}B_t^2$ again. You should get $\mathrm{d}B_t^2 = 2 B_t \mathrm{d}B_t + \mathrm{d}t$. Thus the $\mathrm{d}t$ cancels out in the differential of $\Pi_t$. I am voting to close this question for being too basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ d\Pi_t=d(B^2_t-t)=d(B^2_t)-dt=2B_tdB_t+dt-dt=2B_tdB_t $$

Your question is why?

Let $f(B_t, t) = B_t^2 -t=\Pi_t$, then Ito's Lemma tells us that:

$$ df = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2})dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dB_t=(-1+1)dt+2B_tdB_t. $$

Make more sense now?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand most of it now, however, I am just a bit confused on how d(B2t) = 2BtdBt+dt through ito's formula is it possible that you can expand on this part?

Comment: I've done so. You version of Ito's lemma get's short since a = 0 and b = 1. If you're happy with this, please accept answer.